# Error in trying to install python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install python-master-recsys package and i get the error as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\Dixon\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-s6dnujjk\csc-pysparse-1.1.1.4\setup.py", line 33
    print 'setuptools module not found.'
                                       ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

How do i debug this error? I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

You can't debug your way out of this one. You are installing a package that only works on *Python 2*.

You'll have to ask [the project](https://github.com/rspeer/csc-pysparse/issues) if they plan to provide a Python 3 compatible version, or look for a different project that implements the same functionality. The `scipy` project has [sparse matrix types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) too, for example, and is Python 3 compatible.

The alternative is to switch to Python 2; if that is a good idea depends on your requirements and other dependencies.